# Nagios Performance Data for Binary State (on/off)

Tags: linux, monitoring, grafana, nagios

I am creating a dashboard in Grafana with data from PNP4Nagios for problem resolution. One of the criterias is if there is a connection to a certain service. I have a plugin that verifies this properly. The answer is either connected or not conncted.
Is it possible to generate an output that PNP4Nagios will understand the output so I can add it to my Dashboard?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: So apparently this wasn't properly asked - how to implement it? What should the plugin return in order to PNP to understand the data properly? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the "Performance data" section in the development guidelines: https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html#AEN200 essentially you add a pipe `|` to the end of your output, then return perfdata in the syntax specified. Nagios will pick this up and process it as documented with the commands configured.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for a status plugin for grafana when I found this question.

Pnp4nagios only understands performance data, so as stated by pzkpfw, you need to add that in your check script by adding a pipe after your message and a label=value.  Then if you want to display up/down or ok/warning/critical, there's the [vonage status panel](https://github.com/Vonage/Grafana_Status_panel).